# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32443 with iterator .next on LinkedList

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, indexoutofboundsexception

On my EJB App (Java EE), I proceed a list (LinkedList) to insert into db and I got error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32443

I code as

```
Iterator itertator = myList.iterator();
while (itertator.hasNext()) {         
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject) itertator.next();
    ...
}
```

I wonder as I already use iterator.next why it could has indexOutOfBound?

Full log:

```
Error message: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32443; nested exception is: com.my.exception.MyException
at com.ibm.ejs.container.RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.mapEJBException(RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.java:411)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.mapException(RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.java:113)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException(RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.java:203)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSDeployedSupport.setUncheckedException(EJSDeployedSupport.java:296)
```

My EJB App is accessed by a Java client in multi-threading, the list is implemented in EJB itself by taking the id from the client to find data insert into a linkedlist and then send the list to insert by iterating as above, by randomly it got error.

Anyone could help to find the clue? Or the issue because I am using LinkedList, the size of the object is not enough?

Comment: Since you get a `com.my.exception.MyException`, is that really the location where the exception is thrown? What happens at `RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.java:411` - I assume it's not the code you posted, right?

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you are looking in the wrong place for your error. Iterator.next() shouldn't throw this Exception, unless there were synchronization problems. (The javadoc stresses that LinkedList is not synchronized). So my guess is that's what you'll need to look at. Good luck!

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for feedback, the RemoteExceptionMappingStrategy.java:411 is thrown by the Websphere (that used to deploy the JavaEE app), I'm not sure as well if it could be caused by the application server for such error.

Comment: @S.L. Barth that's what I'm seeking, at my client, I use multi-threading and call the EJB, the code was error in the EJB, at client, I construct LinkedList send to EJB and at EJB I also build data into LinkedList before use it to insert into db. Do you think where should I change for synchronization?

Comment: The place where the Exception is thrown would be a logical place to start. Then you'll have to try to understand how the threads in your code interact - and how they should interact instead.

Comment: @S.L. Bartch, I'm not clear with this. For the logic of that part is very simple as I stated in my description, iterate the list to object and from object add the value to PreparedStatement for insertion to database. I checked again for this error, I used to have in 2009 with the same message, same method: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32443. So I'm wondering with the number "-32443", it's the index, right? Is it because of the size of data in the list? I'm difficult to explain the reason of this error.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you much further. As others pointed out, you may have to look at the place where the `com.my.exception.Exception` originates. I think the -32443 is indeed the index, but it doesn't make sense for the index to have a negative value. That suggests a threading problem. 
I assume, by the way, that Iterator is the standard Java Iterator class, and not a homebrew class that happens to have a bug. That might also be worth checking into.

Comment: Thanks, let's me try to look around more detail. FYI: com.my.exception.MyException is the custom exception that I use to throw when the application (EJB) faced some issue. Another clue, the issue is happening randomly, only in case, we have many data (1 million records to process in multi-threads as example).

Comment: i got same error after my pc with my working programm  goes hibernate. i have no idea why this happend, but i have definite same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that the list isn't thread safe. In case the list is accessed by a number of threads an an other thread accesses the last element at the moment, the `iterator.hasNext()` is true. But when another thread does a `iterator.next()`, then you try to access the next element that isn't available. The fact, that is error happens randomly is another hint for that. Using a thread safe list would be a good idea in this case. Otherwise manually synchronizing the list is necessary:

```
synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but It might not at right place, still got the same error (but randomly). Now I synchronized the lists again but just afraid performance issue; Let's know if it will solve the problem or not;